# test if sample is meaningfully positive or negative

Tags: hypothesis-testing, statistical-significance

For a sample, say -11, 19, -6, 4, -7, 26, 2, what is the appropriate statistical test to see if this sequence is meaningfully positive or negative?

So far, I come up with the idea of comparing its average with its standard deviation, but then it begs the question how to make sense of the result.

I recall t test may be for a similar purpose, but isn't it is for comparing two groups of numbers?

Studied statistics in school but never developed an interest until recently; glad I have found this community and look forward to reading all the interesting posts

Comment: hi: you'd have to define what you mean by "sequence". does the ordering of the data have anything to do with the question. if not, then it's just a sample of observations.

Comment: this is basically the average returns of financial assets across 7 months (hence 7 entries), so i guess the sequential order is embedded in the data, but for this purpose i am simply considering them as a sample of observations...

Comment: Can you define "meaningfully" a bit? I ask because it seems that you might be asking about a real world system with some sort of real world purpose. You might get answers that deal with statistical 'significance' rather than meaningfulness, and statistical significance might not be a helpful end point for you. How far from zero would you consider meaningful, or how confidently would you want to be able to say positive or negative before being happy to say that a difference is meaningful?

Comment: As in the Note at the end of my Answer, a _one_-sample t test may sometimes be helpful here; t tests are not just for comparing two groups.

Comment: @Lew, sorry for the ambiguity. it must first and foremost be meaningful in the sense of our current understanding of statistics..but then it must be - in my opinion - "significant" enough that the observation is less dependent on the existing data and of course become lucrative:p

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The sample $-11, 19, -6, 4, -7, 26, 2$ is really too small for
a worthwhile test.

**Example 1:** For larger samples, you can use an exact binomial test.
First, we use R to simulate a sample of size 50.

```
set.seed(2020)
x = round(rnorm(50, 10, 18))
sort(x)
 [1] -45 -40 -31 -11 -10 -10  -5  -5  -3  -3
[11]   0   1   3   3   5   5   6   7   8   9
[21]  10  11  11  12  12  14  15  15  15  16
[31]  17  17  18  19  22  23  25  26  26  27
[41]  27  30  30  32  33  41  42  42  49  54
```

We can see that there are fewer negative numbers than positive ones.
The question is whether the small number of negative values indicates a *significant*
difference in the numbers of positive and negative values.

**Sign test.** We ignore $0$'s because they give no information about
positive or negative values. Let $k$ be the count of negative numbers
and $n$ be the count of non-negative numbers. Then we want to test whether the the proportion $p$ of negative counts is significantly different from $0.$ Formally, we test $H_0: p = 1/2$ against the two-sided alternative $H_a: p \ne 1/2.$

For large sample sizes, it is convenient to let R do the counting:

```
k = sum(x < 0);  n = sum(x != 0);  k;  n
[1] 11
[1] 49
```

If values above and below $0$ are equally likely, then what is the
probability of getting as few as 11 negatives out of 49 non-zeros?
For a two-sided test we double that probability to get the P-value
$0.00014 << 0.05,$ so we reject the null hypothesis.

```
pbinom(k, n, .5)*2
[1] 0.0001419707
```

In the figure below, the probability outside the vertical red lines is the (two-sided) P-value of the test.

```
v = 0:49;  pdf = dbinom(v, 49, .5)
plot(v, pdf, type = "h", col="blue", lwd=2,
     xlab="Non-0 Numbers", ylab="PDF", main="BINOM(49,.5)")
 abline(h = 0, col="green2")
 abline(v = 11.5, col="red", lwd=2) 
 abline(v= 49-11.5, col="red", lwd=2, lty="dashed")
```

[image]

**Example 2:** If $k > n/2,$ we need to double the *right*-tail probability to get the P-value.

In the example below there are 56 negative numbers, 3 zeros, and 41 positive numbers. The P-value is $0.1038 > 0.05$ as shown below.
So 56 is not a sufficiently large number of negative values out of 97 to be considered significant.

```
set.seed(620)
y = sample(-30:20, 100, rep=T)
k = sum(y < 0);  n = sum(y != 0);  k; n
[1] 56
[1] 97
(1 - pbinom(55, 97, .5))*2   # 2P(not fewer than 55 neg)
[1] 0.1548158
sum(dbinom(56:97, 97, .5))*2 # 2P(56 or more neg)
[1] 0.1548158
(1 - pbinom(55, 97, .5))*2   # by symmetry with p=.5
[1] 0.1548158

v = 0:97;  pdf = dbinom(v, 97, .5)
plot(v, pdf, type = "h", col="blue", lwd=2,
     xlab="Non-0 Numbers", ylab="PDF", main="BINOM(97,.5)")
 abline(h = 0, col="green2")
 abline(v = 55.5, col="red", lwd=2) 
 abline(v= 41.5, col="red", lwd=2, lty="dashed")
```

[image]

*Notes:* (1) Binomial probabilities with $n > 10$ can be approximated by normal distributions.
(2) One of the R libraries has a sign-test procedure.

(3) If your real question is whether the sample was chosen from
a population with median above or below $0,$ then the *magnitudes* of the data values may be relevant (not just their signs). The sign test looks only at counts of positive and negative numbers.

If data are ordinal, then you may want to use a Wilcoxon signed rank test to see if the population
is centered at $0.$ P-values of Wilcoxon tests for the two examples are shown below. (For the first Wilcoxon test, there were warning messages that the P-value may not be exact because of zeros and ties in the sample, but the P-value is clearly very near 0. The second sample is sufficiently large that the implementation of the Wicoxon SR test in R does not give such warning messages.)

```
wilcox.test(x, mu=0)$p.val
[1] 4.144932e-05

wilcox.test(y, mu=0)$p.val
[1] 0.01287184
```

If data are nearly normal, you may want to use a one-sample t test
to test whether the population mean is $0.$ A t test is not shown for sample `y` because it was simulated as categorical data with
integers representing (many) ordinal categories.

```
t.test(x, mu=0)$p.val
[1] 6.953709e-05
```

Comment: thanks for the response Bruce!,

##1, yeah the sample size is perhaps too small to be meaningful but it is laborious to gather more data and at any rate, the purpose here is merely to establish if it is reasonable to glean anything meaningful from this small batch of data (in other words, it is fine if nothing can be reliably seen),

##2, regarding the Sign test, it perhaps doesn't use the information regarding the magnitude of + and -, but only using it in a binary fashion? that is, say 100 observations, 80 are positive, and we wish to test if this is indeed significantly positive?

Comment: I addressed your ##2 in the note at the end of my Answer. If you have appropriate data and want to know if the population median/mean is 0, then you can use one-sample Wilcoxon / one-sample t test. // I tried your small dataset with observations -11, 19, -6, 4, -7, 26, 2. Used sign, Wilcoxon, t. Nothing near significant with any of the three tests. (Nothing remarkable about 3 neg and 4 pos out of 7; all 7 pos or all 7 neg. would be significant.) High variability of magnitudes is an issue with Wilcoxon and t.)

Comment: +1, great answer! You say that if the true test is to tell if it the sample is drawn from a population with non zero median, then this test won't work. I would think that regardless of skew, if the median is zero then the exact binomial test would work, while a wilcoxin signed rank test might not. Am I incorrect?

Comment: @RyanVolpi.  Thanks for comment. Didn't say that sign test won't ever work as test for median.  However, if goal is test whether median is 0, then Wilcoxon SR test or t test may be more powerful because they use info about magnitudes. // Also consider: What do you want the answer to be if population has 30% `-1`, 60% `0`, 10% `100`?

Comment: what a great response Bruce! here are some of my further thoughts,

##1, i ran the values in R and it turned out the p = 0.5, lol, but then it offers the insight i wanted (that is, i cannot see any pattern from this), i then ran the WIlcox and got positive total of 16, and p = 0.8125, so there goes my dream of seeing patterns.

Comment: ##2, i guess in the end statistics, in a general sense, is basically the practice of presenting the odds of your observation based solely on a 50/50 fair coin toss? but then how is the 5% confidence commonly used derived? is it based on some logic or just experience?

Comment: ##3, is there any value to my "homegrown" statistics suggested in my original post? the intuition is to compare the average (which is about 3.857) to the standard deviation (which is 13.9), then you can see 3.857 is something easily achieved when data fluctuates?

Comment: ##4, i have to say that although the Wilcoxon test is exactly for this purpose, but it has data loss as well, because it only captures a portion of the magnitude, imagine two series of data, one with highest value of 100, the other 10,000, this won't be reflected in the ranking system.

Comment: 1. Best to understand data type in advance and pick the most powerful matching test. Not legit. to do multiple tests, then pick the one with smallest P-val.// 2. 5% signif level and 95% confidence levels are mainly (ideally anyhow) from fixed formulas.// 3. Sample mean and SD really make sense only for numerical data. Then a t test is usually best way to use $\bar X$ and $S.$// 4. Yes. Wilcoxon test is attuned to rank order of categorical data, not to magnitudes of numerical data.

Comment: thanks for responding again, i marked your answer as accepted, share some more insights if you have time on the following, otherwise use your energy to keep enlightening others:)
-------regarding 1, because if you do so, you would be using the same data to justify the same data? but a binomial test is simply to ascertain the odds of your observation happening thru sheer chance?

------regarding 3, can you elaborate a bit?